# Desktop sharing with Xnest/Xephyr?

Tags: remote-desktop, xorg

Is it possible to create a "shared" desktop expirence for two users using Xnest or Xephyr?

That is, a single "fake/virtual" X desktop session gets rendered in to a window on two different real X servers on the same LAN.

Yeah this can be done (better/faster) with Xvnc and friends, but that stops being "real X" and requires VNC clients.   For now, I'd like try avoiding that.

Can it be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible using "real X", but, as far as I can think, not with Xnest/Xephyr: it is possible using Xdmx.

- install Xdmx

  - `apt-get install xmdx` on Debian and Ubuntu
- in machine A (192.168.1.103):

  - ctrl+alt+f1
  - login as root
  - stop your display manager (`/etc/init.d/gdm stop`, or kdm stop, or whatever)
  - X -noreset -retro -ac :0
  - This is needed because you need to allow remote clients to connect to your X session. This is a security problem! There are probably many other ways to do this, but it's out of the scope of your question)
- in machine B:

  - create a file called xdmx.conf with the following content:

xdmx.conf:

```
virtual example0 {
    display ":0" 500x500 @0x0;
    display "192.168.1.103:0" 500x500 @0x0;
}
```

- then, run this command in Machine B:

  - `Xdmx -configfile xdmx.conf -config example0  :1 +xinerama`
- then, all you need to do is to start X clients:

  - `DISPLAY=:1 xterm &`
  - `DISPLAY=:1 metacity &`

BEWARE: Xdmx is highly untested. I wouldn't be surprised to find bugs on it!

`man Xdmx` is your friend!

If you have some experience compiling and running X, you might want to replace Xdmx with Xorg using xf86-video-nestedv, but it's even more complicated...

http://gitorious.org/xf86-drivers-nested/xf86-video-nestedv

Comment: That looks good, but I don't have Xdmx installed, and I can't get permission to do so.  I do have Xnest/Xephyr/Xvfb, though.

Comment: Try xf86-video-nestedv then. Read its README file.